# Creating a frequency table to then calculate mean/SD from

Tags: pivot-table, frequency

I have a dataframe that I need to turn into a 3 way freq table:
import pandas as pd

```
data = {'key':  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'year': ['2020', '2020', '2021','2021','2020','2020','2021','2021','2022','2022'],
        'period': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
        'fac':['51000','51000','61000','61000','51000','61000','61000','61000','61000','61000']
         
        }
```

So that I have three columns, fac by year by period.

I tried this:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab([df['fac'],df['year']], df['period'])
print (df2)
```

And I get this:

```
period      1  2
fac   year      
51000 2020  2  1
61000 2020  0  1
      2021  2  2
      2022  1  1
```

But is there a way to get it as three columns? i.e.

```
fac   year  period  count
```

So that I can calculate sum of count, then mean, SD and UCL/LCL?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df2 = pd.crosstab([df["fac"], df["year"]], df["period"])
print(df2.stack().reset_index(name="count"))
```

Prints:

```
     fac  year  period  count
0  51000  2020       1      2
1  51000  2020       2      1
2  61000  2020       1      0
3  61000  2020       2      1
4  61000  2021       1      2
5  61000  2021       2      2
6  61000  2022       1      1
7  61000  2022       2      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!